# Is it possible to reach an orgasm without physical stimulation (masturbation)?

Tags: masturbation, orgasm-climax

Can females or males achieve an orgasm without physical stimulation (masturbation) of the sexual or reproduction organs (vagina, penis, breast)?

Males have nocturnal emissions that work without physical stimulation, can males or females have that during daytime?

If yes, how does one achieve an orgasm this way? Is it mostly psychological?

Comment: Off-topic "If your question is about biological processes without reference to a particular disease, it is off topic"

Comment: @DavidPostill Because *Health is about the academic understanding of health related processes* (paraphrasing the site disclaimer) and masturbation is related to Health, I'd argue that this is on-topic. We have so many questions of this kind that it would be mundane to close them all now.

Comment: @Narusan Shrug. I was only only going by what it said in your help centre.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah I know. It's a beta site, most processes don't work like they should ([meta]) and questions that are blatantly pff-topic like the bikini question never get closed

Comment: Well, there is whole "branch" in porn for that, called "hands free". While not really scientific, it does prove orgasm can be reached without touching the reproduction organ, at least for men. Not sure how they do it though, but that's a different question, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't be such a surprise that [both sexes](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01541556?LI=true) can experience the behaviour described in the question at night, "[involuntarily](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1978-11323-001)".

During waking hours there are mainly [several distractions](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1986-20115-001) in your mind that counteract (previously this would have been "[control](http://journals.lww.com/jonmd/Citation/1958/08000/RECALL_OF_SOME_PHENOMENA_OF_SLEEP__A_Comparative.3.aspx)") these processes.

But since this rather complex yet basic behaviour is a combination of "mind and matter", that is the brain and other organs, this question is primarily to be broken down into: [Are Orgasms in the Mind or the Body? Psychosocial Versus Physiological Correlates of Orgasmic Pleasure and Satisfaction](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00926230590513401)?

There are not only those legends, fairy tales or "reports" from guru like figures or their followers. It seems at least not wholly uncommon to just engage your mind in very [pleasurable thoughts and images to achieve something you desire](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01542589?LI=true).

So, that part of your question seems to have to be answered with a "yes!"
And if it is not physical, then yes again, hm, by definition it has to be psychological. There [has to be a reason](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GK6cct0Vjs).

But now, I have to be afraid, a manual for non-manpulation achievements is unknown to me. I guess you just have to use your own imagination.

Have fun.